# Как избавиться от уведомления "товар удален. отменить?"

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, woocommerce, уведомления

В интернет-магазине установлена последние на сегодня 3.0.5 версия woocommerce и wordpress 4.7 соответственно с стандартной темой storefront. Все изменения вношу через дочернюю тему. Вопрос у меня 1 в 1 как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189428/woocommerce-unset-product-removed-notice-on-cart-page) - как избавиться от всех уведомлений исходящих от корзины, в частности при удалении товара из корзины?
Делаю все по рекомендациям:
перезаписываю файл **notice.php** по пути **storefront-child/woocommerce/notices/notices.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Show messages
 * ... Blabla ... / ... blabla ...
 * @version     1.6.4
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
if ( ! $messages ){
    return;
}
?>
<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : // Change your template code from here
    if ( strpos( $message, 'removed' ) === false ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-info"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></div>
<?php endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

прописываю инструкции в дочерней теме **function.php**

```
function remove_added_to_cart_notice()
{
    $notices = WC()->session->get('wc_notices', array());

    foreach( $notices['notices'] as $key => &$notice){
        if( strpos( $notice, 'removed' ) !== false){
            $added_to_cart_key = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
    unset( $notices['notices'][$added_to_cart_key] );

    WC()->session->set('wc_notices', $notices);
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','remove_added_to_cart_notice',1);
add_action('woocommerce_shortcode_before_product_cat_loop','remove_added_to_cart_notice',1);
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop','remove_added_to_cart_notice',1);
```

а также

```
// Removes Product Successfully Added to Cart
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
function custom_add_to_cart_message() {
 echo '<style>.woocommerce-message {display: none !important;}</style>';
  wc_clear_notices();
}
//Remove Message:
add_action( 'init', 'remove_notices' );
function remove_notices() {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); /*Archive Product*/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); /*Single Product*/
remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'storefront_shop_messages', 1 );
}
```

удаляю в файлах `cart.php` и `cart-empty.php`

```
wc_print_notices();
```

не работает. прописываю в стилях

```
.woocommerce-message {
    display: none !important;
}
```

и все равно - при удалении товара из корзины - вылазит уведомление срабатывающее в файле **class-wc-form-handler.php**

```
$removed_notice .= ' <a href="' . esc_url( WC()->cart->get_undo_url( $cart_item_key ) ) . '">' . __( 'Undo?', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
wc_add_notice( $removed_notice );
```

можно конечно закоментить строчку `wc_add_notice( $removed_notice );`
и тогда работает, но это конечно же не дело - при ближайшем обновлении все слетит
Как же от него избавиться??..

Comment: А зачем от него избавляться??

Comment: Версия WC из будущего?. А ВП без обновлений с дырами и проблемами ? :) Лучше бы с этим научиться разобраться, чем придумывать какую-то ерунду.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну не нужен он мне! я считаю, если покупатель решил удалить товар, то пусть так и будет - это его право, многих это раздражает

Comment: @SeVlad про WC - ок, скорректировал. а по вп какие дыры и проблемы?

Comment: Последняя версия ВП 4.7.4. Почитай какие проблемы решены в 4х проигнорированных тобой технических обновлениях. Одна из них просто дырища.

Comment: @SeVlad во-первых, давайте без тыканий, а во вторых - у меня эта версия и стояла - наизусть до сотых не запоминал

Comment: Нда.. как всё запущено :)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое наверное - скрыть стилями.
Но это глупо - скрывать такую важную инфу.

Comment: да, но сработала только полная запись! усеченная до этого не работала
`.site-content>.col-full>.woocommerce>.woocommerce-message {
 display: none!important;
} `

Comment: да ерунда. дело в кешах. Я только что попробовал .woocommerce-message {
    display: none;
} и все сработало.

Comment: @KAGG Design нет, не ерунда - у меня не срабатывало, перебивало основными стилями. clrl+f5 всегда в работе

Comment: Возможно стили темы. Я пробовал на другой теме, не на storefront.